# Virtual Box - Critical Error - Failed to create the VirtualBoxClient COM object

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I was running a VM when it fell into an error state because of lack of disk space. I killed the process with `kill <pid>`, as it wasn't responding, closed VirtualBox, and freed up some space on my partition. After rebooting the computer, I proceeded to start VirtualBox again, and was presented with this [pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe2jZ.png).

> Failed to create the VirtualBoxClient COM object.
>
> The application will now terminate.
>
> > Document is empty.
> >
> > Location: '/home/adminvb/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml', line 1 (0), column 1.
> >
> > /build/virtualbox-gBjstP/virtualbox-5.0.40-dfsg/src/VBox/Main/src-server/VirtualBoxImpl.cpp[534] (nsresult VirtualBox::init()).
> >
> > > Result Code: 
> > >       NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
> > >
> > > Component: 
> > >       VirtualBoxWrap
> > >
> > > Interface: 
> > >       IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945}

I can't even start VirtualBox's menu. I'm looking for a way to fix it that hopefully doesn't require me to reinstall everything, as I wouldn't like to loose all my virtual machines. (I will do it if it's absolutely necessary.)

I'm running VirtualBox on Linux Mint 18.1 64-bit.